# Filtering objects and and their instances using filter and exclude

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to filter like this:

```
#models.py
class A(models:Model):
    all_letters = models.ManyToManyField(Letters, related_name="all_letters")
    selected_letters = models.ManyToManyField(Letters, related_name="selected_letters")
```

```
#views.py
a = A.objects.get(pk=pk)
array_one = a.all_letters.all().exclude(a.selected_letters.all())
```

I know you can't filter based on instances but is the only equivalent way of doing this using some sort of manual python searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out the items where the relation in reverse (which you *also* named `selected_letters`) do not point to `a`, so:

```
array_one = a.all_letters.exclude(selected_letters=a)
```

Comment: `selected_letters` is a ManyToMany relation with model Letters, and a is an instance of model A. How can we compare two different classes like this?

Comment: @Nick: your `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from `Letter`s to `A`. Normally that is why you should not give `related_name` the same name as the relation "forward".

Comment: @Nick: see https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/giving-related-name-the-same-name-as-the-relation.html